# How to warn the user when edited data in UI so I can warn them of overwriting, or prompt them to save? (Java)

Tags: java, javafx-2

How to warn the user when edited data in UI so I can warn them of overwriting if they load from another source, or prompt them to save? (JavaFX2.2)

I will have over 50 text fields across a number of tabs and 2 or 3 tables with buttons to add and delete rows.

I was wondering whether to have a global 'isDirty' boolean flag and can set onAction handlers on the buttons, but must I set [onKeyTyped](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#onKeyTypedProperty) handlers on every one of the text fields and text areas? (will it slow things?). Does Java keep track of whether any field was edited and if so, can I capture that information from it?

Comment: It would probably be easier to keep all of the data in a separate data model, and compare the data model with the contents of the text fields and tables as a listener of the load and save actions.

Comment: Having a data model will only make things worse IMHO - though obviously I do have a ArrayList (a 'data model') for the Tables. These are config parameters of a device. I am reading the data from the device and putting it on the screen. There can be more than one device connected and we can save from one to another - hence the danger of overwriting unsaved data.

Comment: If you don't want to compare two models, another option is to update the tags of any field that has been updated with a new class "dirty". You can then search for any dirty fields and handle them appropriately.

Comment: @Zylth can you please explain 'update the tags... with a new class dirty'?

Comment: This would be work more tailored for the UI than the backend, but to implement handlers for any changes to then update the class for the text field to also contain 'dirty'

Comment: @Anil. How are you binding textfield.text to the backing bean? Are you extending your (assuming) JPA entity with JavaFX property observable values?

Comment: @Zylth how do you 'update the class for the text field' - are you erferring to the Java class TextField? Isn't it the same as having `volatile boolean isDirty` in all my UI classes?

Comment: @Uluk Biy I am not using JPA. Just JavaFX2.2

Answer (score 0):

A possibly clean solution would be to have a sort of MyWholeDataset class that is filled with data at the startup of the UI and another "cloned" object that is used for the actual UI display.
  Then every time the user changes the data from the UI you change the second object (the cloned one).
  At the end you should implement the Comparable interface. This tells you that there are differences and then you can, for example, have a sort of "getDeltas" method that returns either a set of field names that are different or a hasmap that return field names as keys and an object containing old/new values pairs as value.

Comment: This sounds similar to gilbert's comment above.

Comment: Yes, that should be "The Way", with respect to proper OOP. I've just preferred to clarify since Gilbert did not wrote how to compare the "original" and "GUI-modified" models. In my opinion the best solution would be to use the Comparable interface, letting the models compare to themselves and also provide a method to retrieve the set of differences. That's it.